# Php get name input file when send POST

Tags: php, input, upload

I try many times different methods for get the field´s name when post form and i can get the name of all fields but in the case of input file for upload pics, documents, etc don´t works, i put simple example :

```
<form name="register" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<input type="text" name="op[phone]" value="">
<input type="text" name="op[name]" value="">
<input type="text" name="op[street]" value="">
<input type="file" name="op[upload]" value="" />

</form>
```

**For get all values and names from fields i use this :**

```
   <?php
    
    foreach($_POST['op'] as $key=>$value)
    {
    print "".$key." = ".$value.""

///// FIELD FOR UPLOAD INPUT FILE HERE DON´T SHOW
    }
    
    ?>
```

**The case it´s for get values from input file i need use :**

```
echo $_FILES['op']['name']['upload'];
```

Because inside loop foreach i can´t get name of upload field, my question it´s, if it´s possible get inside loop the name of the field type FILE, because if i can do this, i can process form easy and don´t need process by other way, but i don´t know if it´s possible, because as you can see, in loop only show the fields key and value but no from field for upload, by this i want know if it´s possible get this also inside loop.

**I hope understand my question, thank´s in advanced**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `foreach` loop over `$_FILES['op']['name']`:

```
foreach ($_FILES['op']['name'] as $key => $filename) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['op']['tmp_name'][$key];
    // and similar code for all the other elements in $_FILES items
}
```

Comment: The case it´s i need detect all this inside loop i indicate in my example, detect input file name but in the other loop because if use your example for example, i need process this information by other step

Comment: You can't do it in the same loop, since files aren't in `$_POST`.